# Does $T_n$ converge to the identity operator $I$ by the operator norm in $C[0,1]?$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Consider a sequence of operators $T_n$ :$C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$ given by the formula $$(T_nx)(t)=x(t^{1+\frac{1}{n}}),\ t\in [0,1], \ n\in \mathbb{N}.$$
> Does $T_n$ converge to the identity operator $I$ by the operator norm in $C[0,1]?$

I showed that $T_n$ is a linear and bounded operator and $T_nx\rightarrow x$ by the norm in $C[0,1]$.
I think the answer is no, but I couldn't find any contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ consider the continuous linear function $x_n$ with $x_n(t)=1$ for all $t\ge 1/2$ and $x_n(t)=0$ for all $t\le \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1+1/n}$. Then there holds

$$\|T_n x_n - x_n \| = \sup_{t\in[0,1]}\left|x_n\left(t^{1+\frac{1}{n}}\right)-x_n(t)\right|\ge \left|x_n\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1+\frac{1}{n}}\right) - x_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right|=1.$$

There fore $\|T_n-Id\|=\sup_{x:\|x\|=1}\|T_nx-x\|\ge 1.$